# Custom FileNameEditor

Tags: c#, uitypeeditor

I want to implement a custom FileNameEditor; I want to set my own filter and I want to be able to select multiple files.

```
public class Settings
{
    [EditorAttribute(typeof(FileNamesEditor), typeof(System.Drawing.Design.UITypeEditor))]
    public string FileNames { get; set; }
}

public class FileNamesEditor : FileNameEditor
{
    protected override void InitializeDialog(OpenFileDialog openFileDialog)
    {
        openFileDialog.Multiselect = true;
        openFileDialog.Filter = "Word|*.docx|All|*.*";
        base.InitializeDialog(openFileDialog);

    }
}
```

This ignores the filter property and although I am able to select multiple files I can't assign them to my Settings.FileNames property because Settings.FileNames is of type string[] and the result of the derived class is string.
How can I tell my derived class to return the openFileDialog's FileNames and how to make the filter work? What am I missing?

Comment: I don't really understand your question, the dialog has a property called FileNames which you can do a foreach over. I don't undstand the Settings class either. What has to be in the FileNames property? Want the files comma seperated?

Comment: The settings class will hold several settings like input files to compute, paths to helper assemblies, output format options, globalization settings and other... it will be serialized when saving the settings and loaded at each programm start to save the user from selecting these at each start of the application.
The input files should be choosable using an OpenFileDialog... the settings are a generic class shown in a propertygrid.

Answer (score 3):

The original code worked for me, except for a needed re-ordering. You need to call the base.Initialize before your changes, or they get overwritten (debugging will show it nicely)

```
public class FileNamesEditor : FileNameEditor
{
    protected override void InitializeDialog(OpenFileDialog openFileDialog)
    {
        base.InitializeDialog(openFileDialog);
        openFileDialog.Multiselect = true;
        openFileDialog.Filter = "Word|*.docx|All|*.*";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps use an ArrayEditor for the string[]

```
public class Settings
{
  [EditorAttribute(typeof(System.ComponentModel.Design.ArrayEditor),  typeof(System.Drawing.Design.UITypeEditor))]
  public string[] FileNames { get ; set; }
}
```

Comment: I want to use the FileNameEditor as UITypeEditor, but need to apply my settings to it.

Comment: take a look at http://winterdom.com/2006/08/acustomuitypeeditorforactivityproperties

Answer (score 0):

Okay, this is how it works...

```
public class FileNamesEditor : UITypeEditor
{
    private OpenFileDialog ofd;
    public override UITypeEditorEditStyle GetEditStyle(ITypeDescriptorContext context)
    {
        return UITypeEditorEditStyle.Modal;
    }
    public override object EditValue(ITypeDescriptorContext context, IServiceProvider provider, object value)
    {
        if ((context != null) && (provider != null))
        {
            IWindowsFormsEditorService editorService =
            (IWindowsFormsEditorService)
            provider.GetService(typeof(IWindowsFormsEditorService));
            if (editorService != null)
            {
                ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
                ofd.Multiselect = true;
                ofd.Filter = "Word|*.docx|All|*.*";
                ofd.FileName = "";
                if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    return ofd.FileNames;
                }
            }
        }
        return base.EditValue(context, provider, value);
    }
}
```

Comment: the correct answer, and use it with 
[Editor(typeof(FileNamesEditor), typeof(UITypeEditor))]